# Android emulator on android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, archlinux, android-version

i have a problem with Android Studio 3.1 and his emulator.
If i emulate the Marshmallow version  or a version a higher version of 5.0 the emulator works fine.
if i try to emulate Lollipop or a older version of android the emulator stuck: in kit-kat and jelly bean the button power of emulator don't reacts, if i presso 1000 times it works one time,maybe . In Icecream the phone in emulator is stuck, it don't reacts and sometimes the display flash.
With the new version of android the only problem is that if i  don't use cool boot when i exit from the emulator and it save the session, many times the emulator stuck and no way to stop it or kill the process.

I have archlinux and i use android studio,adv for create the device and the official emulator of android (for business reasons I can not change emulator). I have check if the kvm work's and it's ok.

It's maybe beacuase the version of android are too old and they aren't supported by the emulator?